# asp.net validators ends up in same place

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm writing an application with multiple validators (date, required, regexp for format) on the same page. They validate correctly, but they turn up in the same place. That is, they don't turn up next to the validated field, they are appended to another validation error message next to a completely other field.

Here goes example code snippets:

Number:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator class="IMSIValidators" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Enter digits only, no other characters" ControlToValidate="IMSIRangeTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="AllValidators" ValidationExpression="[0-9]+"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>

<p class="IMSIEditLabels">Operator: <asp:TextBox ID="OperatorTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" class="IMSIValidators" Text="Enter the customer" ControlToValidate="OperatorTextBox" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="AllValidators"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<p class="IMSIEditLabels">Requested by:<asp:TextBox ID="RequestedTextBox" class="IMSIEditInputItems" runat="server" ValidationGroup="AllValidators"></asp:TextBox></p>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" Text="Enter a full name" ControlToValidate="RequestedTextBox" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

I've tried all ways that I can think of, such as setting Display="Dynamic" and ValidationGroup="AllValidators". No combination works for me.

I've tried to set their position in a CSS class, but then they came up on top of each other (which is logical).

Any input is greatly appreciated. I'm getting SO frustrated :)

//Eva-Lotta

Comment: Can you paste your html of controls plus their validators?

Comment: Based on the information you have provided, it's impossible to help you. You need to provide your html markup for controls that are not showing properly, if you really want to be helped.

Comment: That's weird - I thought I did that, but it seems like it doesn't show up. I will update.

Comment: What is the validation group of button that is firing all the validators? Also, you only need to specify it for validators and the control like button which is causing validation to occur.

Comment: Please mentioned the exact CSS for thesse classes: IMSIValidators, IMSIEditLabels and IMSIEditInputItems. Most likely its the CSS that is causing your problem.

Comment: It was the css class! it had a relative position, and it worked fine when i removed it. That's such a great relief, thanks!